# Batch string substitution using variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to use string substitution with existing variables called from another file but it will not accept the variable.

My code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Call Number.bat
Set Num=%EN%
set /p str=<String.bat
call set str=%%str:dt!EN!=dt%%
call set str=%%str:Tm!EN!=Tm%%
```

String.bat:

```
Set dt4=2015-10-24 
Set Tm4=11:01:32.82
```

Number.bat:

```
Rem Number.bat
Set EN=4
Rem This Number Changes Constantly!
```

My code should take `String.bat` and `Number.bat` and erase the number beside the two variables I set, but when I have finished this it just gives me:

```
dt4=2015-10-24 
Tm4=11:01:32.82
```

But I want:

```
dt=2015-10-24 
Tm=11:01:32.82
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please comment out or remove the `@echo off` line in order to see what statements are actually being executed. Also, an `echo %str%` after the `set /p` line would be informative. What part of this code do you think would remove the number?

Comment: using `!` for for variables requires [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) but I cant see `setloca enableDelayedExpansion` in your code.

Comment: Change `call set str=%%str:dt!EN!=dt%%` by `call set str=%%str:dt%EN%=dt%%`. However, if you insert `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` then this is simpler: `set str=!str:dt%EN%=dt!`

Comment: Oops. Meant to Put 'setlocal enabledelayedexpansion' in there. I have tried all you have suggested and none of them seem to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to accomplish.  Your last three lines of code in particular don't make sense.  Please elaborate.